# Since when apt install can be used over apt-get install?

Tags: debian, apt-get, apt

I've find recently that we can use the more recent `apt install`, `remove`... over the ancestral `apt-get install`. I didn't know that before. Because I have some scripts that install packages accross wide range of OSes, i would like to know since when `apt install` is available in Debian and Ubuntu?

Comment: I would recommend against using apt on scripts, since the commands aren't script stable yet. If you need to use scripts use apt-get instead. BTW, the only practical difference between apt and apt-get is that the former is shorter to type and with colors (which will polute your log output).

Comment: The principal advantage is better dependencies handling, more like aptitude.

Comment: I'd note that there also exists a lesser-known package manager, [cupt](http://packages.debian.org/cupt) with its own custom dependency solver touted by its author to be of good quality. I did not test it (`apt` covers 99% or my needs with `aptitude` coming second for advanced search queries).

Comment: What? Package dependency handling is managed by the apt library, like apt-get. [There isn't any indication in the very short sources that indicates otherwise](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/apt/apt.git/tree/cmdline/apt.cc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Jessie — the now stable release (Debian 8.0).

Note that this wrapper, while useful, does not yet cover 100% of what older `apt-whatever` programs do; namely there's no `apt cache` currently.